# Is there a zero knowledge proof of knowledge of a Waters sigature?

Tags: signature, zero-knowledge-proofs

I am looking for a ZK PoK of a digital signature. I have seen constructions that work for ElGamal signatures (see this older [paper](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-540-47942-0_9)), but need to work with Waters signatures, as described [here](https://eprint.iacr.org/2004/180.pdf).

Has anyone seen a construction that could work in this case?

Comment: Yes, of course, you can build a ZK proof/argument of knowledge of the Waters signature by Fiat-Shamir heuristic or [Groth-Sahai 07](https://eprint.iacr.org/2007/155.pdf) proof method.  The statement of this ZK proof/argument is "the ciphertext $c$ contains a Water signature $\sigma$ on $m$.". And the related witnesses are the signature $\sigma$ and your secret key $\alpha$.

Comment: Many thanks @mingalex - I am finally learning the proper appreciation for Groth-Sahai. Do you happen to be aware of any software libraries that support the construction of proofs in their framework?

Comment: There was an [implementation](https://github.com/gijsvl/groth-sahai) of the Groth-Sahai NIZK. You can launch it directly without installing PBC lib, if you do not want to use the type D&G pairing.